# Capturing and playing AMR packets

Tags: stream, save, playback, rtp

I make a VoLTE call using AMR. I see the AMR packets. right click and select the source as the filter. I see all the incoming AMR packets. Next I go to analyze an select Decode as. Set filed for RTP and current for AMR. I do ok and go to Telephony. Select RTP Streams and I see the one that shows the duration of 18.12. If I select RTP stream Analysis I see all the Packets. When I go to Play Streams I only get the one packet. How do I save and get all the RTP packets?

Thanks;
David

Only able to play one packet. I read on the WEB that once you get the RTP you go to Statistics and save. I do not see that under Statistics.

Answer (score -1):

To save and retrieve all RTP packets while capturing and playing AMR packets, you can follow these steps:

-
Capture the RTP packets:
Use a packet capturing tool like Wireshark to capture the RTP packets. Configure the filter to capture the specific AMR packets you're interested in. Right-click on the packet, select "Decode as," and set the fields for RTP and current for AMR decoding.

- Analyze the RTP streams:
  After capturing the packets, go to Telephony -> RTP Streams. Look for the stream with the desired duration. This stream represents the sequence of RTP packets.
- Save the RTP packets:
  In Wireshark, there isn't a direct option to save all RTP packets under the "Statistics" menu. However, you can export the RTP packets to a PCAP file for further analysis and playback. Here's an example code snippet using the Wireshark TShark command-line tool:

  tshark -r captured_packets.pcap -Y "rtp" -w rtp_packets.pcap
- Retrieve and play the RTP packets:
  To retrieve and play all the RTP packets, you can use a media player that supports the AMR format. Here's an example code snippet using the GStreamer library in Python:

> import subprocess
>
> pcap_file = 'rtp_packets.pcap' output_file = 'output.amr'
>
> // Convert the RTP packets to AMR format subprocess.run(['tshark',
> '-r', pcap_file, '-T', 'fields', '-e', 'rtp.payload', '|',
> 'amrnb-decoder', '>', output_file], shell=True)
>
> // Play the AMR audio file subprocess.run(['aplay', output_file])

Comment: This looks like it might be ChatGPT